# Create Parameters dynamically from JSON in React

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, dynamically-generated

i'm trying to create Parameters dynamically.

```
{({ destinations: { question2, question3 } }) => (
              <div className="buttonContainer">
                <button onClick={question2}>Yes</button>
                <button onClick={question3}>No</button>
              </div>
)}
```

The `destionations: { question2, question3 }` should be created dynamically from a Json that looks like this:

```
const data = {
  content: {
    body: [
      {
        nextTag: ["question2", "question3"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not enough code to help you

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski please help

Comment: What are `destinations`? There is nothing like this in your object

Comment: @KonradLinkowski the destinations should not change, it should fill the values from the nextTag of the JSON into the destinations

Comment: @KonradLinkowski ???